# Php get jpg file from a folder as array

Tags: php, random

help me to get files from a folder in array.
I am trying to get all jpg file name in `array` from a folder `images`.
and after that use `rand` to change css background Randomly.

JPG files from a folder in arry;

```
$images=array("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg");
```

then use the `rand` to load images randomly

```
echo '<style>body{background:url('.$images[array_rand($images)].')no-repeat;';
```

Comment: Sooo... What's the question? Do you have what you've tried that's inadequate?

Comment: I dont know how to get files from a folder in array

Comment: [Manual is your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) - find function written by williamcomartin at gmail dot com

Comment: [glob](http://us3.php.net/glob): `echo '<style>body{background:url('.array_rand(glob("images/*.jpg")).')no-repeat;';`

Comment: @AaronW. - I'm guessing that would probably make a good answer, although there are other ways too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a directory to [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get an array of all files in that directory.
Maybe use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) then to filter out any non-images by file extension.

```
    $files = scandir( '/image/path' );

    function images_only( $file )
    {
      return preg_match( '/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i', $file );
    }

    $files = array_filter( $files, 'images_only' );
```

**$files** should now contain only the images from the image path.

Answer (score 1):

[glob](https://www.php.net/glob) it

**edited** with array_rand fix

```
$images = glob("images/*.jpg");
// may want to verify that the $images array has elements before echoing
echo '<style>body{background:url('.$images[array_rand($images)].') no-repeat;';
```

Comment: Is the path correct? Try debugging to make sure it's populating correctly

Comment: `array_rand()` returns a random **key** only.